# In SSRS,How to change the values of sub report on click of value in main report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Consider a report with main and sub report. Country-->State-->District.

Country is a parameter. on choose of country, State name belongs to the countries will be listed in Main report.

On click of state name in main report respective District name should be listed in Sub report. 
I came to know that this is drill through report and can be done by Action in properties.

My requirement is, i need both report should display in same page i.e. below the main report, but currently district report is opening in new sheet if it is a drill through. 
i tried using sub report , but the values are not changing on click of state in main report.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking for on-demand execution of subreports. That isn't possible in SSRS. The report is rendered all at once and will only be rendered again if you change report parameters and rerun it.

[SSRS 2008 R2 Drill Down On-Demand to Sub Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472009/ssrs-2008-r2-drill-down-on-demand-to-sub-report)